Spectrum of matrix under linear transformation into lower dimension
Given $P \in \mathbb{R}^{(n-1)\times n}$ with orthonormal rows and $\text{ker}(P)=\text{span}(1_n)$, $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with row-sum equal to 1, I want to prove that:
$$\exists B\in \mathbb{R}^{(n-1)\times (n-1)}, PA=BP$$
Additionally:
$$\text{spectrum}(A)=\text{spectrum}(B) \cup \{1\}$$
I think the first part is easy, as $PP^T=I_{n-1}$ and therefore: $B=PAP^T$. Is this correct?
The second part is clear intuitively, as 1 is an eigenvalue of $A$ associated with eigenvector $1_n$ which is being projected into nullspace by $P$. I tried proving this using various determinant properties and calculating the eigenvalues directly. However, I can not find a way to prove this formally, although it's supposed to be quite simple.
Thank you.

What exactly do you mean by $1$, is it the vector $(1,1,...,1)$?

Had a typo, sorry. $1_n$ is the n-dimensional column vector of 1's and 1 is just the value 1.

For the second part, if $Av = \lambda v$,  $PA v = BP v$ and  $\lambda Pv = B (Pv)$, i.e. all eigenvalues of $A$ are also eigenvalues of $B$. There is one exception: $1_n$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with 1 as its eigenvalue while $B P1_n = B0=0$.

Let $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, i.e. $Av=\lambda v$. Then we have
$
\begin{align*}
PA&=BP\\
\implies PAv&=BPv\\
\implies \lambda Pv &= BPv
\end{align*}
$
Case $(1)$: $Pv=0_{n-1}$. Then $v\in\text{ker}(P)=\text{span}(1_n)$, and $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ specifically with eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.
Case $(2)$: $Pv\neq 0_{n-1}$. Then $Pv$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.
Thus, $\lambda\in\text{spectrum}(A)\implies\lambda\in\text{spectrum}(B)\vee\lambda=1$.
Now let $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1\times n-1}$ be an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then we have
$
\begin{align*}
PA&=BP\\
\implies P^TB&=AP^T\\
\implies P^TBv&=AP^Tv\\
\implies \lambda P^Tv &= AP^Tv
\end{align*}
$
Case $(1)$: $P^Tv=0_{n}$...? Well, it looks like $P$ has a nullity of $1$ and thus a rank of $n-1$. And we know that $P$ and $P^T$ must have the same rank. So $P^T$ also has a rank of $n-1$, which is equal to its number of columns, which means it has nullity $0$ (trivial kernel). So $P^Tv=0_{n}$ is impossible.
Case $(2)$: $P^Tv\neq 0_{n}$. Then $P^Tv$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.
Thus, $\lambda\in\text{spectrum}(B)\implies\lambda\in\text{spectrum}(A)$.
I think these two implications should be enough to prove that $\text{spectrum}(A)=\text{spectrum}(B)\cup\{1\}$.
(Note: I am assuming $v$ is not a zero vector.)
